# iOS AWS SDK overrides the Content-Type property

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set the Content-Type property of my file as follows but when I inspect the file in the web, the content-type is reset to `application/octet-stream`

```
    S3PutObjectRequest *request = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:key inBucket:bucket];
    request.filename            = filePath;
    request.contentType         = [self mimeTypeForFileAtPath:operation.filePath]; //Returns @"image/jpeg"
    operation.operation         = [self.manager upload:request];
```

At the filepath resides a NSData written to a file with a UUID as filename (no file extension).

Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `binary/octet-stream`?  That's what the S3 service assigns if no `Content-Type` is present in the request.

Comment: Can you print what is the value of request.contentType before sending the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this problem. Instead of providing the filename, I proved the data to the `S3PutObjectRequest`

```
request.data                = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:operation.filePath];
request.contentType         = [self mimeTypeForFileAtPath:operation.filePath];
```